# Why can I not import statsmodels api?

Tags: python, import, scipy, statsmodels, factorial

In a ARIMA case I want to import statsmodel.api as am to use it for SARIMAX. But when I want to import it I get some Error that PyCharm can not import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc' (lib\site-packages\scipy\misc__init__.py). At the moment I'm trying to update scipy via commandline under Windows (pip install --upgrade scipy) but this gives me TimeOut Errors.

Does someone know where the problem is? I read something about updates/ version errors, but didnt find a solution that worked out for me.

Thank you in advance! :)

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(data.MemoryUsedPercent, trend='n', order=(0,1,0), seasonal_order=(1,1,1,144))
results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kunkelk/PycharmProjects/PE_II/Test_II.py", line 105, in 
    import statsmodels.api as sm
  File "C:\Users\kunkelk\PycharmProjects\PE_II\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py", line 16, in 
    from .discrete.discrete_model import (Poisson, Logit, Probit,
  File "C:\Users\kunkelk\PycharmProjects\PE_II\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py", line 45, in 
    from statsmodels.distributions import genpoisson_p
  File "C:\Users\kunkelk\PycharmProjects\PE_II\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions__init__.py", line 2, in 
    from .edgeworth import ExpandedNormal
  File "C:\Users\kunkelk\PycharmProjects\PE_II\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions\edgeworth.py", line 7, in 
    from scipy.misc import factorial
ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc' (C:\Users\kunkelk\PycharmProjects\PE_II\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc__init__.py)

Comment: I use pip version: 19.0.3 and scipy version: 1.3.0 and statsmodels 0.9.0

Comment: See https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5759

Answer (score -1):

`import statsmodels.formula.api as sm`